# Unicode from JSON works fine for text view on android, assign to string, and it does not work

Tags: android, string, unicode

Basically if I do something like

```
myTextView.setText(jsonObj.getString(USER_NAME));
```

My text view will show the correct text : あ

if I do the following:

```
String myText = jsonObj.getString(USER_NAME);
myTextView.setText(myText);
```

The text also appears correct & shows : あ

In my use case. I have a class RowRecord & constructor & class var

```
public class RowRecord {
   public String mUserName = "";

   public RowRecord (JSONObject jsonObj, Context context) {
       mUserName = munzee.getString(Constants.MUNZEE_FRIENDLY_NAME);
   }
}
```

I then have my arrayAdapter

```
public class MyArray extends ArrayAdapter<RowRecord>
```

When overriding getView

```
@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    RowRecord rowRecord = getItem(position);
.
.
.
    TextView myUserName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
    txtUserName.setText(rowRecord.mUserName);
```

It ends up displaying like 
&#12354;

So I went and tried to do the following

```
String myText= new String( jsonObj.getString(USER_NAME).getBytes(), "UTF-16" );
```

Unfortunately it displayed it as some square boxes.

I then

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: The "correct" and "incorrect" outputs in the question show up identically for me (each is a single U+3042).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the raw JSON string, and make sure strings are in the same encoding your code expects. 
Your safest bet is to use UTF-8 throughout.